# URL structure. Why is a non-existing page BAD in the structure? domain.com/structure1/MISSINGPAGE/page1

Tags: url, drupal

An stakeholder wants the path of a page listing different hammers to be like this:

mydomain.com/tools/metal/hammers

There is a "/tools" page but there is no "/tools/metal" subpage. if you go to mydomain.com/tools/metal/ its a 404.

The reason they want "metal" in the URL, is because in the visual menu of the website we visually separate "tools" by the material they are made for (The site is not about tools or hammers, I am just setting a simple example).

I argued the structure of the URL should reflect the structure of the site, and that if a user deletes "hammer" from the URL and hits enter to see all the metal tools, they will find a broken page. And another developer went "Oh but if there is no harm done then lets just leave it as is, as it reflects the structure of tools even if we have no page for it, the hammers ARE made of metal, and the url reflects that. We can just add a redirect from /tools/metal to /tools to avoid the broken link". So now I am looking for any documentation as to why that is bad/wrong practice. Anything I can point at from a reputable source.

This is probably one of the weirdest questions I have ever made in stack overflow, so I do apologize.

Comment: Jakob Nielsen coined the term "hackable URLs" for this back in 1999 already (https://www.nngroup.com/articles/url-as-ui/), and I still think it is a good principle to follow. If you implement a redirect so that `/tools/metal` won't lead to a 404/403 though, I think that should be enough here in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Really interesting question, I'm not sure if this will work as reputable source, but if you take stackoverflow as an example, navigating to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript
points to javascript questions,

while navigating to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/
just redirects you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions

so assuming stackoverflow site follows best practices (I sure hope so) we can say that this is ok

Comment: Woah you are right @saintic Stack overflow does this. 
Maybe its not such a horrible idea after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can create/generate "metal" page with views, you obviously classify products by material. Use one of the Drupal breadcrumb modules, some allow you to add taxonomy pages in structure.